# Parse/Decode a json using php

Tags: php, json

Although I've searched around Stackoverflow, I did not find the answer, which fits to my problem. The UseCase: I want to access a server-side json to use it with the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example) or with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp/). Both of them need a proper json file.
Find bellow my approach:

Json-File **(sampledata.json)**

```
[{
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T12:15:00+02:00",
    "value": 235.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T12:30:00+02:00",
    "value": 235.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T12:45:00+02:00",
    "value": 236.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:00:00+02:00",
    "value": 234.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:15:00+02:00",
    "value": 234.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:30:00+02:00",
    "value": 234.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:45:00+02:00",
    "value": 234.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:00:00+02:00",
    "value": 235.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:15:00+02:00",
    "value": 234.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:30:00+02:00",
    "value": 233.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:45:00+02:00",
    "value": 233.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T15:00:00+02:00",
    "value": 233.0
}, {
    "timestamp": "2014-05-22T15:15:00+02:00",
    "value": 233.0
}]
```

php-File to read the json File:

```
<?php
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.
$json = file_get_contents("sampledata.json");
var_dump($json);
?>
```

The generated output looks like the follwoing:

```
string(832) "[{ "timestamp": "2014-05-22T12:15:00+02:00", "value": 235.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T12:30:00+02:00", "value": 235.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T12:45:00+02:00", "value": 236.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:00:00+02:00", "value": 234.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:15:00+02:00", "value": 234.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:30:00+02:00", "value": 234.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T13:45:00+02:00", "value": 234.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:00:00+02:00", "value": 235.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:15:00+02:00", "value": 234.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:30:00+02:00", "value": 233.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T14:45:00+02:00", "value": 233.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T15:00:00+02:00", "value": 233.0 }, { "timestamp": "2014-05-22T15:15:00+02:00", "value": 233.0 }]"
```

As you can see, this is not a proper json-output. The first characters `string(832) "` and the last `"` have to be emilated - then it would work. I've already tried to use the php function `json_decode` but this didn't solve my problem. In fact it generates also an array and no json object. 
So my question would be:

1. How to read the json file?
2. How to format it correctly using the timestamp and value tag?
3. How to make a correct json-dump?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using var_dump? That's always going to give you the type of the variable. Very useful for debugging, but not if you want to use it in code. Try `echo $json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the json object as is, there's no need to run it through `json_decode` or `json_encode`. Just `file_get_contents` and you have the contents of the file (it's an accurate function name). Then pass it to the Google API or whatever else you want to use. Your problem is coming from `var_dump`, where you seem to think that the `string(832)` is part of the variable `$json`'s contents, when it is actually just part of `var_dump`'s output.

Comment: alternative is json_encode(json_decode($elements)) to check if the string is not valid json

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. It was even easier than thought. Just one line of code and I'm happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode json_decode

```
$json_o = json_decode(file_get_contents("sampledata.json")); // object
$json_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("sampledata.json", true)); // associative array
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong, but this is not that, what I want to have, is it? Both give me an array, but I want to have a correctly formated json-object. In fact I what to have the same output as it already exits as the input. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @shlomm Why do you need a json formatter? So it is presented more readable?

Comment: @Marek I want to proceed with the json-output to use it with [Google's Chart API - Server-side Data Source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example). To do so, I need to format the input to a proper json file. And apart from that...I would like to know it :) I'm quite new to php and those stuff...